# Why is my application not detecting a shake gesture?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to enable shake gestures within my application but I'm having a problem.

I have different view controllers, but on one of them (not the main view controller for the application) nothing happens in response to a shake gesture.  What could be the problem?

The relevant code is as follows:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}


-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {


 NSLog (@"SHAKED");

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `-viewDidAppear:` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking motion, not event. Like this:

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {       
    NSLog(@"SHOOK");
    }
}
```